# How to use inject resource from server (like ManagedExecutorService) in Junit-Test of Spring

Tags: spring, concurrency, junit, wildfly

I use ManagedExecutorService for concurrency in my code like this:

```
 @Resource
private ManagedExecutorService defaultManagedExecutorService;
```

It works fine if I build them and deploy them on my server, because the i reference the resource ManagedExecutorService on the server:

```
<managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
```

But I have my Junit test based on Spring. And to run this test I don't need any server. So I got the following exception:

```
Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(mappedName=, shareable=true, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}
```

It seems that the spring can not find my resource from the server.

What can I do now?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "mock" that functionality, meaning simulate the real deal with a similar implementation that doesn't actually go to the server and retrieve the JNDI resource, but uses a fake result.

There is a package in Spring that offers some functionality for testing JNDI resources, you can find its source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/mock/jndi).

To get started with using classes in that package, I would look at Spring's own testing classes where those JNDI mocking classes are used. For example, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/test/java/org/springframework/transaction/JndiJtaTransactionManagerTests.java#L56) how those classes are used to test a JTA transaction manager.

I haven actually used this, but I would try something like this:

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;
....
ManagedExecutorService mes = mock(ManagedExecutorService.class);
ExpectedLookupTemplate jndiTemplate = new ExpectedLookupTemplate();
jndiTemplate.addObject("java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default", mes);
...
```

Or you can take a look at [this](https://fossies.org/linux/www/wildfly-8.0.0.Final-src.tar.gz/wildfly-8.0.0.Final-src/clustering/common/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/clustering/concurrent/ManagedExecutorServiceTest.java) for another testing class that needs to mock a `ManagedExecutorService`.